# Opening a tcl program from another

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a tcl application that I want to open from another tcl application. When I open it the opened app appears within the main app, over the top of quarter of it. Does anyone know how to make the opened app appear as a seperate window?

I think it may have something to do with WM WINDOW.

Comment: Does the second app use the `toplevel` command? Or does it just use `.` as the name of the top level window? How exactly do you "open" it?

Comment: The second app is made up of 3 labelframes(.rs, .bs & .ss) with widgets within them i.e .rs.label, .bs.checkbutton.

Comment: Those labelframes are being packed (or placed or whatever) into the first app's toplevel window -- you need to put them into a new toplevel window.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the source command, you don't really start another application. You're just loading additional code into your existing application. To actually start another application you can use `exec tclsh otherapp.tcl`.

To get two separate windows when sourcing two files into the same interpreter, they should use seperate toplevels, as Glenn mentioned.

If you don't want to modify the file you are sourcing, another possibility is to load each file into their own interpreter.

```
interp create app2
app2 eval {source otherapp.tcl}
```

Make sure your app files contain `package require Tk` when you want to use this technique.